# Testing ARM-Templates with ARM-TTK

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I am trying to use ARM-TTK for doing unit testing for my ARM templates and ensuring that the templates follow uniformity. I am only running few tests.
We are using Azure Repos as our VCS

I have incorporated this in my AZDO pipeline as a pre PR merge task which is in the form of a branch policy, so that before a PR is merged, these tests will run and validate all the templates that are pushed to the main branch.
But the problem is, the tests are returning false positives even though there are no issues with the JSON files.
According to this link [ARM-TTK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/test-toolkit) it seems there has to be one azuredeploy.json or maintemplate.json and all the other files are tested as linked templates.
I have JSON files with other names pertaining to the function of the template like win_vm_deploy.json, function_app-deploy.json etc etc.
It is not possible for me to have all the files as linked templates to the azuredeploy.json or maintemplate.json as mentioned in the URL.

I would also like to run the selected tests against the files loaded in the repo automatically and not specify a particular file to run the tests against.

So does that mean that in my situation i won't be able to use the ARM-TTK and utilize the unit tests?

What is the best way to check my templates in my particular folder and utilize some of the unit tests that i choose from ARM-TTK, but then i don't have to have a main template and the other templates as linked templates.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

When we are working with several people to create a complex deployment it is recommended to use separate JSON files linked to an **azureDeploy.json** or a **mainTemplate.json** file. But it's not mandatory to do the same in every case.

To test one file in that folder, add the `-File` parameter. However, the folder must still have a main template named *azuredeploy.json* or *maintemplate.json*. In your case all files need to be specified in a script. There is no such shortcut available for automation.

You can customize the default test or even create your own test. You can implement you own set of rules by authoring the custom tests. A custom test needs to be placed in the correct directory:

```
_/arm-ttk/testcases/deploymentTemplate_
```

You can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/arm-template-test/4-custom-tests) for more information.

Also try this tasks for [integration with Azure Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/test-toolkit#integrate-with-azure-pipelines).